# How do I specify the fetch_style when using a PDO prepared statement and the traversal interface?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

My pdo connection is set up to return standard objects, and I can use the traversal interface to iterate over the results as follows:

```
$stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($arr);
foreach($stmt as $rs) {
    //$rs is a stdObject since the pdo connection is set up to return stdObjects
}
```

Per http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php, I can specify the fetch_style and similarily itterate over the results as follows:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($stmt as $rs) {
    //$rs is an array even though pdo connection is set up to return stdObject since I included `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`
}
```

What I want, however, is to use a prepared statement when my pdo connection is set up to return standard objects, and use the traversal interface to iterate over the results and return arrays:

```
$stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($arr);
foreach($stmt as $rs) {
    // pdo connection is set up to return stdObject.  What can be done to make $rs an array?
}
```

How can this be done?

Note that typecasting to an array is not an acceptable answer as not using the traversal interface in the first place would be a better approach.

However, stating that it is not possible (if true) is an acceptable answer.

Comment: So do I understand that your `ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` is `FETCH_OBJ` but you want to be able to automatically override that to `FETCH_ASSOC` only when iterating the PDOStatement object? Interesting question, I'm not sure it's possible without extending PDO or manually changing the fetch mode before iterating.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Yes, you understand correctly.  If overly complicated, using a `while` loop with `fetch()`  is not the end of the world and I can surely do so.  I do, however, like to be consistent when possible and if would do so if as straight forward as how it can be accomplished with `query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.

Comment: RTFM ~ http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php

Comment: @Phil  Would this require setting it, performing the query, and then setting it back?  If so, I believe not attempting to use the traversal interface in the first place would be a preferred solution.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean about _"setting it back"_. The setting is isolated to the `PDOStatement` instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first stop should always be the PHP manual ~ [PDOStatement::setFetchMode](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php)

```
$stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($arr);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($stmt as $rs) {
    // $rs is an array
}
```

This will set the *fetch-mode* only for the particular `PDOStatement` instance and will not have any affect on future queries.

Comment: Thank you Phil.  Please see my response to your comment.  PS.  I did not think about using `PDOStatement::setFetchMode` so thanks again, but still doesn't meet the overall objective of maximizing consistence and minimizing chances of error.

Comment: I really don't understand your question

Comment: Ah, I see now (and should have initially) how it just applies to the statement in question.  As such, I feel it is a reasonable approach.  Thanks